# Ref current is always null when rendering my element for the first time?

Tags: reactjs

So my problem is simple I guess, I want that when I click an element, my input got the focus in, so this is my methods and constructor on my component :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.textInput = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      searchValue: ""
    };
  }
  activateSearchZone = action => {
    this.props.activateSearchZone(action);
    console.log(this.textInput);
    this.textInput.current.focus();

  };

  handleSearchZone = event => {
    let searchValue = event.target.value;
    this.props.searchForUsers(searchValue, { isSearching: true });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.searchForUsers(searchValue, {
        isSearching: false,
        searchDone: true
      });
    }, 1000);
    this.setState({
      searchValue
    });
  };
```

And this is my component :

```
   {this.props.searchList.activated && (
          <div className="search-bar__zone">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} size="xs"></FontAwesomeIcon>
            <input
              placeholder="Search"
              onChange={event => this.handleSearchZone(event)}
              value={this.state.searchValue}
              type="text"
              ref={this.textInput}
            ></input>
            <FontAwesomeIcon
              icon={faTimesCircle}
              onClick={() => this.activateSearchZone(false)}
            ></FontAwesomeIcon>
          </div>
  )}
```

The console log shows that the current value is null, I understand now why, it is because my element is just rendered I think, but I want the focus in my input when clicking.

How can I do that ?

An help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried `<input type="text"  autoFocus>` ??. I think this will auto focus the input field

Comment: @AkhilAravind I did not know about this before, I looked for it in the documentation and that's what I need actually, it worked, Thanks, I can mark your answer as correct if you want to write that as answer.

Comment: sure will post answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can focus an `input` element with `autofocus` attribute. In react, it will be like `<input type="text" autoFocus />`, this will do the job.

For detailed explanation, please refer the link https://davidwalsh.name/react-autofocus

Answer (score 2):

That's because `react` doesn't knows about the `ref` on initial render. You need to use `forwardRef`. It is HOC that wraps your component and tells react that there is some ref. And it will not render that until it is available. Here is an example:

```
const FancyButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton">
    {props.children}
  </button>
));
```